# Issues publishing wcf service - oracle.dataAccess error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, wcf

I have an application that has a UI layer, wcf layer that interacts with the database layer.  They are all in the same solution but seperate projects within the solution.  Each is setup to target x86.

My issue is i continually get the error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

There are 2 ways I can make this go away.

1. Create a new wcf project, copy in my code and create a reference in the UI layer.  It then begins to work.
2. Skip referencing the wcf layer and reference the database layter instead.  This is not the way the users want it to work however.

Number 1 will work as long as I do not do the following:

1. Attempt to publish (Publish to my local machine so the same place development is happening).  When I try and publish the app and the wcf this causes the reference or the service it self i am not sure to completely break.  if i blow the service away and try and create another service reference to it i get this error.  The only way I have found to make it go away is to create another project and copy the code as i mention.

I think i have everything installed correctly as like i mention, it all seems to work without issue until i publish (only local as i mention at this point.).  I am a little concerned that when I publish to the server that I am going to have issues like this so only attempting this locally currently.

I should also note that when I am publishing this to my local IIS i am setting the reference app pool to enable 32 bit applications too.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong or how to get this to publish correctly?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that your reference to the Oracle dll in properties is set to copy local.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have done that but still the same result.  I can see it in the bin folder too.  Seems strange to me that this would work while i am building and debugging the solution but when it comes to deploying on the same machine this happens.

Comment: That is a good question.  i am not sure how could i tell?  i don't see any entries for this in uninstall applications.  I remember having to install this that and the other thing to try and get this to work so it is possible there are multiple.

Comment: I have sql plus up but not sure what I am looking fore here?  Under all programs on the machine I have oraclienhome1, 2, 3 as well as OraHome1121.  I am guessing these were created during the trials of getting this thing semi working.

Comment: Determining what version of oracle client and odp you're using

Comment: I think this might have something to do with it.  Thanks for the hint.  I am going to run through removing these to attempt to reinstall.